# CentOS on HP Proliant Gen9 New Kernel hangs

Tags: centos, kernel

Would really appreciate a little help:

Installed CentOs 7 on a HP DL380 Proliant Gen9 without a problem.

Did a yum update also without a problem.

Installed the long term and mainline kernels to get the most up to date for security. Both installed fine but both kernels fail to load and hang.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-latest-kernel-on-centos-linux-7-using-yum-command/

LTS 4.11 / ML 5.1

The only difference I see is they are both missing .vmlinuz**.hmac files.
Are these critical ?

I have no error messages or logs except when it boots with the old kernel. (3.10.*)

I did yum install mainline kernel with: 
"yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml"
and then did a reboot.

Did I miss a step ?

Would the new kernels have a LVM problem ?
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3133621

How can I debug this? Can I provide more information ?

Thanks

Julian

Comment: I realize that this is not what you're asking, but you state that you install the LTS/ML kernels "for security". Are you aware that RHEL (the upstream distro for CentOS) backports security patches into the 3.x kernel that is provided with RHEL? More ontopic: have you tried booting into emergency mode? (`systemd.unit=emergency.target` on the kernel command line)

Comment: I alway skips things!<br/>Warning: Please note that installing a new kernel not officially supported by both RHEL and CentOS project. It is also possible that your system may not boot. As the kernel-ml/lt packages are built from the source tar balls provided by kernel.org without any modifications to the code, they can contain some differences when compared to the CentOS/RHEL distribution kernels. Hence, you must keep backups of all important files before you do this.

Comment: Your answer is clear and anwsers my problem. I would like to know what the problem is but that is not critical. I cannot get into emergency mode or where do I put this. press e at grub and there?  Thanks Edward

Comment: Yes, you would enter 'e' at the Grub screen to see a boot prompt. Just add the `systemd.unit=emergency.target` at the end of the kernel boot line and start booting. Refer to: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Grub2.
And yes, I would stronly advise against using a proprietary kernel in an enterprise OS. If you want cutting edge, just install Fedora :-)